# PHP - Como enviar dados de uma tabela para um form

Tags: php

Olá, Eu estou com um problema para pegar os *dados* de uma tabela *estática* e mandar para uma outra página com o form para preencher os `input` desse `form` com os *dados* da tabela.
Gostaria de ajuda.

na listaCliente.php tem:

```
 <table class="table">
    <tr class="tb_column tb_cabecalho">
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Nome</td>
        <td>E-mail</td>
        <td>Ações</td>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
    <form action="" method="get">
        <?php
        $id = "1";
        $nome = "José Carlos";
        $email = "carlosnt135@hotmail.com";
        ?>
        <tr class="cinza">
            <td><?php echo $id; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo$nome; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo$email; ?></td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn_padrao btn_margin" type="submit" title="Editar" alt="[Editar]"><a href="index.php?link=4">Editar</a></button>
                <button class="btn_padrao btn_margin" title="Excluir" alt="[Excluir]">Excluir</button>
                <button class="btn_padrao btn_margin" title="Matricular" alt="[Matricular]">Matricular</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </form>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

na cadastroCliente.php tem:

```
<form>
        <?php
        @$nome = $_GET['nome'];
        @$email = $_GET['email'];
        echo $nome;
        ?>
        <label>Nome</label>
        <input type="text" name="nome" value="<?php echo $nome; ?>" />

        <label>E-mail</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>"/>

        <div class="me">
            <label>Senha</label>
            <input type="text" name="senha" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Ao invés de criar um *form* dentro da tabela e usar `buttons` para as ações, porque não usa links e passar os valores pela URL? Exemplo:

```
 <a class="btn_padrao btn_margin" href="cadastroCliente.php?nome=<?= $nome ?>&email=<?= $email ?>">Editar</a>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado. Me ajudou muito. Deu certo

Answer (score 0):

Como ja foi passado acredito que seria melhor ja passar os dados por GET na propria url e fazer o tratamento dos dados na pagina do formulario, agora se pretende pegar de uma tabela e mandar para um form na mesma página vc pode identificar as (td) com id ou name e usar javascript para levar os dados.

tipo

```js
var tdnome = getElementById(id da td nome);
var campodoform = getElementById(id campo form);
campodoform.value = tdnome.innerHTML;
```

Comment: Muito obrigado por sua ajuda

Answer (score 0):

O jeito mais simples de resolver, sem JavaScript, sem gambiarra, é usando campos ocultos.

Para isso, você vai precisar de um `form` para cada linha.

Exemplo:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr class="tb_column tb_cabecalho">
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Nome</td>
        <td>E-mail</td>
        <td>Ações</td>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        $id = "1";
        $nome = "José Carlos";
        $email = "carlosnt135@hotmail.com";
        ?>
        <tr class="cinza">
            <td><?php echo $id; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $nome; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $email; ?></td>
            <td>
              <form action="index.php" method="get">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id ?>"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="nome" value="<?php echo $nome ?>"/>
                <input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $email ?>"/>
                <button class="btn_padrao btn_margin" type="submit" title="Editar" alt="[Editar]" name="action" value="editar">Editar</button>
                <button class="btn_padrao btn_margin" title="Excluir" alt="[Excluir]" name="action" value="excluir">Excluir</button>
                <button class="btn_padrao btn_margin" title="Matricular" alt="[Matricular]" name="action" value="matricular">Matricular</button>
              </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Entretanto, eu em geral não é recomendável ficar passando valores por toda a internet quando você tem eles no servidor.

Portanto, o método mais seguro e eficiente seria apenas passar o `id` como parâmetro da URL e carregar os demais dados na página de cadastro.

Exemplo:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr class="tb_column tb_cabecalho">
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Nome</td>
        <td>E-mail</td>
        <td>Ações</td>
    </tr>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        $id = "1";
        $nome = "José Carlos";
        $email = "carlosnt135@hotmail.com";
        ?>
        <tr class="cinza">
            <td><?php echo $id; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $nome; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $email; ?></td>
            <td>
                <a href="index.php?id=<?php echo $id ?>" class="btn_padrao btn_margin">Editar</a>
                <a href="excluir.php?id=<?php echo $id ?>" class="btn_padrao btn_margin">Excluir</s>
                <a href="matricula.php?id=<?php echo $id ?>" class="btn_padrao btn_margin">Matricular</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Essa abordagem diminui bastante o risco de ataques como XSS (Cross Site Scripting) e deixa seu código mais simples.